# How to add element without submitting to another page

Tags: javascript, django, django-views, xmlhttprequest

I would like to add a topping to my pizza using XMLHttpRequest without submitting to another page but I can't wrap my mind around how to implement it. So far I'm posting to `add_topping` route and getting a JsonResponse without any problem. But instead of going to the view, I would like to do it with JavaScript. I have already searched for similar problems but or they are all with PHP or with jquery but I would like to implement it using normal JavaScript with XMLHttpResponse.

### HTML

```
    <form id="add_topping" action="{% url 'orders:add_topping' %}" method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}

      <div class="form-row align-items-center">

        <div class="form-group col-auto">
          <select class="form-control" name="topping_selected"  id="topping_selected">
            {% for topping in topping_list %}
            <option value="{{ topping }}">{{ topping }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
          </select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-auto">
          <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="submit">Add topping</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

### views.py

```py
def add_topping(request):

    # If request is not a POST request, return index
    if request.method == 'POST':

        # Get the data from the POST request
        topping_selected = request.POST.get('topping_selected')

        return JsonResponse({"success":True, "topping_added": topping_selected})

    # Else return false
    return JsonResponse({"success":False})
```

### JavaScript

```
// Function to add topping
document.querySelector('#add_topping').onsubmit = function() {

  // Create request object
  const request = new XMLHttpRequest();

  // Variables to determine the size and topping selected from the document
  let topping_selected = document.querySelector('#topping_selected').value;

  // Initialize the request
  request.open('POST', '/add_topping', true);

  // Callback function when the function completes
  request.onreadystatechange() = () => {

    // Extract JSON data from the request object
    const data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

    console.log(data);

    // Give feedback to user upon success/failure
    if(data.success) {
      const p = document.createElement("p");
      p.innerHTML = "Topping added.";
      // p.append();

      // Append it to the #summary_before_add_to_cart div
      document.querySelector('#summary_before_add_to_cart').append(p);
    }
    else {
      const p = document.createElement("p");
      p.innerHTML = "No topping added yet.";

      // Append it to the #summary_before_add_to_cart div
      document.querySelector('#summary_before_add_to_cart').append(p);
    }

    // Add data to send with the request
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append('topping_selected', topping_selected);

    // Send the request
    request.send(data);

    // Stop submitting to another page
    return false;

  };
};
```

Thanks for any kind of help/advice. I know that this is basic stuff but I have to understand how to implement this. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

here is the code that can help you do not forget to set RequestHeader as csrftoken else it will give you error

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', '{% url 'app:current_url' %}');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xhr.onload = function() {
console.log('Signed in as: ' + xhr.responseText);
};
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", getCookie('csrftoken'));
xhr.send();
```

so in your case :

```
    document.querySelector('#add_topping').onsubmit = function() {
      const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      let topping_selected = document.querySelector('#topping_selected').value;
      request.open('POST', '/add_topping', true);
      request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
      request.onload = function() {
        const data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

        console.log(data);
        if(data.success) {
          const p = document.createElement("p");
          p.innerHTML = "Topping added.";



          document.querySelector('#summary_before_add_to_cart').append(p);
        }
        else {
          const p = document.createElement("p");
          p.innerHTML = "No topping added yet.";


          document.querySelector('#summary_before_add_to_cart').append(p);
        }


        const data = new FormData();
        data.append('topping_selected', topping_selected);
   function getCookie(name) {
        var cookieValue = null;
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
            var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                    cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return cookieValue;
    }

        request.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", getCookie('csrftoken'));
        request.send(data);
        return false;

      };
    };
```

Comment: Thanks but I can't figure it out. I think that I don't have to post to the `/add_topping` route in the form. Instead I should use XMLHttpRequest to do this job. It is not clear to me how to solve this problem. Can you help maybe giving the example with my code?

Comment: Thanks, the JavaScript part is clear from the beginning. But all together it still doesn't work because or the HTML part or wrong or the view part. Because if I post it like this to the `add_topping` view it returns a JSON response as expected. If I don't put the post method to form I can see all the info passed through the URL to the same page but nothing happens!

Comment: can't help more